# How do I convert a large XML file to a CSV file?

Tags: python-3.x, xml, csv

Because of the need to build the knowledge graph, I wanted to convert a 3.39GB XML data file to CSV format, but when I tried Python, my computer ran out of memory.

**The following code：**

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

def xml_to_csv(path):
    xml_list = []
    for xml_file in glob.glob(path + '/Badges.xml'): 
        print('**********************************')
        print(xml_file)
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        # for member in root.findall('row'):
        for member in root.findall('row'):
            value = (member.attrib.get('Id', ''),
                     member.attrib.get('UserId', ''),
                     member.attrib.get('Name', ''),
                     member.attrib.get('Date', ''),
                     member.attrib.get('Class', ''),
                     member.attrib.get('TagBased', ''),
                     )
            xml_list.append(value)



    column_name = ['Id', 'UserId', 'Name', 'Date', 'Class','TagBased']
    xml_df = pd.DataFrame(xml_list, columns = column_name)
    # print('----------------')
    # print(xml_df)
    return xml_df


if __name__ == "__main__":

    xml_path = 'D:/【论文】/【数据集】/1-StackOverflow数据集-2008-2021/stackoverflow.com-Badges'
    print(os.path.exists(xml_path))
    xml_df = xml_to_csv(xml_path)
    print('**********************************')
    print(xml_df)
  
    xml_df.to_csv('D:/【论文】/【数据集】/1-StackOverflow数据集-2008-2021/stackoverflow.com-Badges/Badges.csv', index = None)
    print('Successfully converted xml to csv.')
```

Comment: Is there a way to split this large file? Or read the data item by item, instead of reading it all the way into computer memory and formatting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various technologies for streamed processing of XML. One of them is XSLT 3.0, where you would write

```
<xsl:mode streamable="yes"/>
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="row">
  <xsl:value-of select="@Id, @UserId, @Name, @Class, @TagBased"
     separator=","/>
  <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried MySQL, imported the XML data set files into the database, then exported them to CSV format and processed 82.2GB files in just 3 hours.
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIiLu.png][1]